# c# picturebox dock problems

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I wish to dock my picturebox to right-top corner of my form, but when I use
  `pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;`
the image from picturebox is in the right place, but its background color creates a streatched stripe for whole height of my form. It doesn't appera if I use
 `pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;`

I have no idea why is it so, can anyone help me?

I wish it was sticked to right top corner and when I try to resize the window to smaller - make it disappear, when I try to resize  to bigger window - keep it still sticked to righttop corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the picturebox like you want it to be placed and set the `Anchor` property like that:

```
pictureBox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;
```

and your picturebox behaves like you want it to.

Comment: my picturebox appears in left top corner instead of right top corner.

Comment: @user898569: You have to place the picture at the point of your window you want it to be. Set the Dock property to `pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.None;` and the Anchor property like I stated in my answer and it works...